# How can I extend the d3.js selection whit a custom filter function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've many use of this filter function that just skips null data:

```
selection
    .data(array).enter()
    .filter(function(d) { return d === null ? null : this })
    .append("something")
```

So I decided to simplify code extending the selection with a **notnull** function:

```
d3.selection.enter.prototype.notnull = function() {
    return this.filter(function(d) {
        return d === null ? null : this 
    })
}
```

So I can simply the code this way:

```
selection
    .data(array).enter()
    .notnull()
    .append("something")
```

And it seems to work, but evidently I've some problem with the return value, because I get this error:

> TypeError: selection.data(...).enter(...).notnull(...).append is not a function

And now I'm really struggling to realize why. Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

The question was uncorrect, the first example had to be:

```
selection
    .data(array).enter()
    .append("something")
    .filter(function(d) { return d === null ? null : this })
```

but this leaves a lot of empty svg entities, so the way to go, as Ruben has pointed out, is to use the Array.filter on the data array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a snippet for your original filter code - without a custom function - and found that it does two things. Firstly, it throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: selection.data(...).enter(...).filter(...).append is not a function` and secondly, it logs the argument `filter` is called with.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, null, 5, 6, 7];

var selection = d3.select('body').selectAll('span');

selection
  .data(array).enter()
  .filter(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    return d === null ? null : this;
  })
  .append("span")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
```

Here, we see that `d` is actually an array of values, so `.filter()` is called on an array of arrays, not just on an array itself. To fix this, you can do two things: you can decide to filter your data before passing it to d3js as follows `.data(array.filter(function(d) { return return d !== null; }));`or you can filter the values after you've added `span` tags for all of them. The snippet below shows your code in a functioning way:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, null, 5, 6, 7];

var selection = d3.select('body').selectAll('span');

d3.selection.prototype.notnull = function() {
  return this.filter(function(d) {
    return d === null ? null : this
  })
}

selection
  .data(array).enter()
  .append("span")
  .notnull()
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, that's right! I've always used filter *after* append, and this explains why I've some a lot of empty SVG entries! So the latter works, but leaves this annoying empty tags, I'll go for the first. Plenty of thanks!